# Programmatically style an input element's "focus" pseudo-class with Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

So far I'm using event listeners to set the `:focus` pseudo-class of an input element:

```
const element = document.getElementById("myElementID");

element.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  e.target.style.borderColor = "red";
});

element.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
  e.target.style.borderColor = "";
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goldorak/cx6sqo21/5/)

Although this works, is there a more elegant or idiomatic way to achieve the same thing with `Vue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to listen to native events using vanilla JS syntax and `getElementById` when using Vue. You can specify the v-on-handler directly on the element in the template, like so:

```js
// Vue SFC
<template>
  <div>
    <input @blur="doSomething" @focus="doSomethingElse" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    // Both methods receive the same native dom event as a vanilla listener would
    doSomething(e) {
      e.target.style.borderColor = "red";
    },
    doSomethingElse(e) {
      e.target.style.borderColor = "";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you only want to apply this simple styling then a pure CSS solution, as provided by Manas Khandelwal, is sufficient and preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with CSS. Like this:

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myElementID" />
```